# QVector<T> operator= and operator[]

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program for my friends during my summer time and I occurred really strange problem.

I'm assigning a QVector< T > to other QVector< T > with operator= in my homemade template class and then trying to check whethere this 2nd QVector< T > have any elements. First, I'm checking it's size and it's good, but when I use operator[] and function GetName() which is a member of class T.

Here's some code:

```
 template <template T> class Turniej {
 private:
  QVector<T>* list_;
  QVector<Stol<T> > stoly_;
  int round_;
  int max_rounds_;
  Turniej() {round_=1;}
 public:
  static Turniej& GetTurniej() {
   static Turniej turniej;
   return turniej; }
  void SetList(QVector<T> *list) {list_=list; }
  QVector<T>& GetList() {return *list_;}
  //Some other irrelevant methods
 };
```

Then I invoke SetList() function with reference to QVector filled with 2 objects of Gracz class

```
  Turniej<Gracz>::GetTurniej().SetList(&list)
```

And when I'm finally trying to get to the list_ object in Turniej class by code below, I get this error:
ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range", file .../QtCore/qvector.h, line 356

```
 qDebug()<<Turniej<Gracz>::GetTurniej().GetList()[0].GetName();
```

Where GetName() returns some QString and for certain that method exists in Gracz class.

I would really appreciate any help, because I'm stuck with it for 2 days and have completely no idea what's going on. What is strange, I was trying to google that error but I haven't found any topic with error in that particular line of qvector.h.
I'm using Qt 5.0.2 with Qt Creator

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you dealing with QVector by pointer? My guess is that the pointer is invalid by the time you access it. Just use a plain QVector.

Comment: returning the reference to a dereferenced pointer is a bad idea, you could dereference a NULL or uninitialized pointer!!!

Comment: I did changed pointers to plain QVectors and tried to use operator= in SetList() function by `list_=list` and still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call SetList, you are transferring the ownership of the list, are you shure you are not deleting it (or it is not getting deleted automatically) afterwards?

Comment: Yeah, is is deleted afterwards, but now I'm operating on plain QVector and the effect is stiil the same. And right now I'm copying elements to a new QVector. Element list exists in a window, that invokes constructor of a new window and destroys itself. In exactly that order.

Comment: Seriously, do you think I can give you an answer based on that comment? You should probably mark this question as solved, as the problem has been found, and open a new one where you put the current code

Answer (score 0):

Change `list_=list;` to `list_ = new QVector(list)`. Maybe your vector is modified somewhere outside of your class? You're just keeping reference to vector given to your method, it seems like copying is what you want.

**updated**
I see your class is a singleton. Always remember to think twice before making a class a singleton - it's not a thing you want to have in your code, and it should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm using singleton but I've earlier written about the same program. Only difference was class Turniej wasn't template class, which I need it to be, and everything worked perfectly good.

Comment: It seems like there are several instances of your singleton - one for each `T`. Maybe the problem is there?